# How to configure source lookup paths npm run babel-node similar to browserify's paths?

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

This is how I include my own modules at the moment:

```
import AjaxUtils from 'common/util/AjaxUtils";
```

This is achieved using the "**paths**" options of **browserify**.
This is working out perfectly on client side.

Now I'm trying to render the same application on server side with a Express server:

```
npm run babel-node -- server.js
```

(The reason I'm using **babel-node** is that my application is written using ES6/ ECMAScript 2015 syntax.)

The error I'm seeing is:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'common/utils/AjaxUtils'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app//components/MyApp.jsx:3:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at normalLoader (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .jsx] (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

How can configure `npm run` `babel-node` to look up modules in specific folders like browserify's "paths" option?

My **babel** and **babel-core** version is 5.8.35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting environment variable `NODE_PATH` does it for me

Answer (score 0):

in bashrc or zshrc..

`$NODE_PATH="$(nvm which default)"`